# How to change the default font for the whole project in react native expo project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to change the default font that my project uses so I dont have to go and specifically add styles font-family to all my components to change the font. But I cannot find and documentation on how to change the default font for whole project.

This is my code, I am loading the font as it says in the docs. I have also a theme folder, and returning the index.ts file with the fonts set.

app/_layout.ts

```
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
// import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { Urbanist_400Regular, useFonts } from "@expo-google-fonts/urbanist";
// import { Anton_400Regular, useFonts } from "@expo-google-fonts/anton";
import { theme } from "@/constants/theme";

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    Urbanist_400Regular,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        {/* <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} /> */}
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

assets/fonts/index.ts

```
import { colors } from "./colors";
import { space, lineHeights } from "./spacing";
import { sizes } from "./sizes";
import { fonts, fontSizes, fontWeights } from "./fonts";
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";

export const theme = {
  colors,
  space,
  lineHeights,
  sizes,
  fonts,
  fontSizes,
  fontWeights,
};
```

fonts.ts

```
export const fonts = {
  body: "Urbanist_400Regular",
  heading: "Urbanist_400Regular",
  monospace: "Urbanist_400Regular",
};

export const fontWeights = {
  regular: 400,
  medium: 500,
  bold: 700,
};

export const fontSizes = {
  caption: "12px",
  button: "14px",
  body: "16px",
  title: "20px",
  h5: "24px",
  h4: "34px",
  h3: "45px",
  h2: "56px",
  h1: "112px",
};
```

Answer (score -1):

first, install the font you want in your project and inside your **app.json**
assign the location of your font inside that file like this->

```
  {
  "expo": {
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["assets/fonts/*"]
  }
}
```

and define your font in a file like customeFont.js

```
import { Font } from 'expo';

export const loadCustomFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'your-custom-font': require('./assets/fonts/YourCustomFont-Regular.ttf'),
    // You can also define other styles like 'bold', 'italic', etc. if needed
  });
};
```

and inside your app.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { loadCustomFonts } from './customeFont';

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadFontsAsync = async () => {
      await loadCustomFonts();
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    loadFontsAsync();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or a loading screen
  }

  return (
    // Your main app component
  );
}
```

now you are good to go you can use your custom font inside your app like

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  customText: {
    fontFamily: 'your-custom-font',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.customText}>Hello, Custom Font!</Text>
  </View>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Arun thank you but I know how to load them, but how do i set it up as a default font so i dont have to go and manually add the fontfamily to all of my components, how do i set it that the whole application just uses the font, I know how to load them